# How do I use XMLUnit to compare only certain parts of files?

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing

How do I use XMLUnit to compare 2 or more nodes (of the same name) in 2 different files?

I have 2 XML files that look like this:

```
<SearchResults>
  <result type="header"> ...ignore this.... </result>
  <result type="secondheader">...ignore this....</result>
  <result>....data1....</result>
  <result>....data2....</result>
  <result>....data3....</result>
  <result type="footer">...ignore this....</result>
</SearchResults>
```

And here is my method that I use to compare so far.   The problem is that I do not want to compare the parts of the xml that have a result tag with any kind of attribute flag on them.   How can I do this?

```
public void compareXMLEqualityToLastTest() throws Exception { 
  System.out.println("Checking differences.");
  File firstFile = new File("C:\\Eclipse\\workspace\\Tests\\log\\" +
              "Test_2.xml");
  String file1sub = readXMLFromFile(firstFile);
  File secondFile= new File("C:\\Eclipse\\workspace\\Tests\\log\\" +
              "Test_1.xml");
  String file2sub = readXMLFromFile(secondFile);
  assertXMLNotEqual("files are equal", file1sub, file2sub );
  assertXMLEqual("files are not equal", file1sub, file2sub );
}
```

I found a vague suggestion to use a ElementQualifier on page 5 of the XMLUnit manual, but I don't understand it yet.   I wouldn't know how to tell it which nodes to compare.

```
Diff myDiff = new Diff(file1sub, file2sub);
      myDiff.overrideElementQualifier(new ElementNameAndTextQualifier());
      assertXMLEqual("But they are equal when an ElementQualifier controls " +
    "which test element is compared with each control element", myDiff, true);
```

Should I follow that route and add this class to my project?

```
org.apache.wink.test.diff.DiffWithAttributeQualifier
```

The thought crossed my mind to put the  nodes into a NodeList and then use *org.custommonkey.xmlunit.compareNodeList*  but that feels like that is a hack.  Is there a better way than that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to use XPath Tests? I imagine something like this to work

```
//select all elements which don't have a type attribute
String xpath = "//result[not(@type)]";
assertXpathsEqual(xpath, file1sub, xpath, file1sub2)
```

Comment: that looks like the answer as long as assertXpathsEqual is able to get a NodeList and not just a single node.  ill try it.  thanks very much for the idea.

Comment: thank you!  this worked:  String xpath = "//result[not(@type)]"; 
      assertXpathsEqual(xpath, file1sub, xpath, file2sub);